Count inside aGroup_Concat
Is it possible to count occurences of strings like 'pass' and 'fail' inside a Group_Concat()?
I have the following situation there I need to count the occurences of 'pass' and 'fail'
I need to count how often 'pass' and 'fail' occurs in
GROUP_CONCAT(parameters.calc_value0 ORDER BY samples.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n')

Here is my current situation so far
SELECT parametertypes.name as 'Test',

CASE   
   WHEN (IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(parameters.calc_value0 ORDER BY samples.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n'), (GROUP_CONCAT(parameters.value0 ORDER BY samples.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n'))) LIKE '%pass%')
    THEN CONCAT('<span class="green">', if(IFNULL(parameters.calc_value0, parameters.value0) LIKE '%pass%', COUNT(samples.id), COUNT(samples.id)) , ' pass </span>', CHAR(10), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(samples.DDF_Artikelbezeichnung) ORDER BY samples.name ASC SEPARATOR '\n')) 
   
   ELSE '-'
END as 'Samples Pass',

CASE    
    
   WHEN (IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(parameters.calc_value0 ORDER BY samples.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n'), (GROUP_CONCAT(parameters.value0 ORDER BY samples.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n'))) LIKE '%fail%')
    THEN CONCAT('<span class="red">', if(IFNULL(parameters.calc_value0, parameters.value0) LIKE '%fail%', COUNT(samples.id), COUNT(samples.id)), ' fail </span>', CHAR(10), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(samples.DDF_Artikelbezeichnung) ORDER BY samples.name ASC SEPARATOR '\n'))
  
   ELSE '-'
END as 'Samples Fail',

CASE     
   WHEN (IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(parameters.calc_value0 ORDER BY samples.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n'), (GROUP_CONCAT(parameters.value0 ORDER BY samples.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n'))) LIKE '%documentation%')
    THEN CONCAT('<span class="orange">', if(IFNULL(parameters.calc_value0, parameters.value0) LIKE '%documentation%', COUNT(samples.id), COUNT(samples.id)), ' documentation </span>',CHAR(10), samples.DDF_Artikelbezeichnung)      
  
   ELSE '-'
END as 'Samples Documentation'


FROM samples  
JOIN parameters ON parameters.sample_id = samples.id
JOIN parametertypes ON parametertypes.id = parameters.parametertype_id 

WHERE samples.order_id IN(1268)
AND samples.visible_to != 'deleted'
AND parameters.calc_value0 IS NOT NULL 

GROUP BY parametertypes.id -- , samples.DDF_Artikelbezeichnung


This are my current results. There should be 9 pass and 1 fail for first row.

When you need to count the amount of definite substring occurences in some string value then use the next pattern:
SELECT (LENGTH(@string) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@string, @substring, ''))) / (LENGTH(@substring)) AS amount
...

where @string is a value/column/expression to be investigated, and @substring is a substring value/column/expression to be searched for.
This method does not count the overlapped substrings - for example, counting for 'abab' in xxabababyy will produce 1 and not 2.
If you need to count for more than one substring then count for each substring separately.
